# Displaying Spring Dropdown in JSP if user does NOT have value in it

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Displaying Spring Dropdown in JSP if user does NOT have value in it..  I am trying to find out how to write some Spring code that will not display the following dropdown if the user has a value in the borough field coming back from the server?

```
<form:select path="borough">
 <form:option value="Staten Island">Staten Island</form:option>
 <form:option value="Queens">Queens</form:option>
 <form:option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</form:option>
 <form:option value="Bronx">Bronx</form:option>
 <form:option value="Manhattan">Manhattan</form:option>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jstl conditional tag to get this done

```
<c:if test="${empty borough}">
    <form:select path="borough">
    <form:option value="Staten Island">Staten Island</form:option>
    <form:option value="Queens">Queens</form:option>
    <form:option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</form:option>
    <form:option value="Bronx">Bronx</form:option>
    <form:option value="Manhattan">Manhattan</form:option>
    </form:select>  
</c:if>
```

As per comment:

You can achieve if else by using `c:choose`

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty borough}">
        <form:select path="borough">
        <form:option value="Staten Island">Staten Island</form:option>
        <form:option value="Queens">Queens</form:option>
        <form:option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</form:option>
        <form:option value="Bronx">Bronx</form:option>
        <form:option value="Manhattan">Manhattan</form:option>
        </form:select>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        This is the else block, you can have multiple when clause so it will become if else if else code
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Some [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html)

Comment: can you give me more details on the test="${empty borough}".. I think I got it working but how can I put a elese on this too?

Comment: it does not work. it looks ike it always thinks borough is empty

Comment: that shouldnt be the case what is the value which is contained in borough ?

Comment: I am going to give you credit for the first part of this but check out the following link for the source code, output etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707580/displaying-code-in-jsp-if-user-does-not-have-value-in-it-cchoose-not-workin

Comment: here was the issue... What is the "commandName" attribute in your <form:form>? You will need to reference borough as a property of your command object. For example:

<c:when test="${empty command.borough}">