# Displaying Code in JSP if user does NOT have value in it - <c:choose> not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I am trying to add some code to my Spring JSP to display a list of boroughs if the user does not have one setup in the system.

Here is my JSP code:

```
<form:hidden path="borough" />
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${empty borough}">
                            <tr>
                            <td width="129"><span class="ast">*</span>Borough: </td>
                            <td width="361">
                                    <form:select path="borough">
                                          <form:option value="Staten Island">Staten Island</form:option>
                                          <form:option value="Queens">Queens</form:option>
                                          <form:option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</form:option>
                                          <form:option value="Bronx">Bronx</form:option>
                                          <form:option value="Manhattan">Manhattan</form:option>
                                    </form:select>              
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                        <form:hidden path="borough" />
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
```

The hidden field before the c:choose is for debugging only.  Here is my output:

```
<input id="borough" name="borough" type="hidden" value="Queens"/>



                            <tr>
                            <td width="129"><span class="ast">*</span>Borough: </td>
                            <td width="361">
                                    <select id="borough" name="borough">
                                          <option value="Staten Island">Staten Island</option>
                                          <option value="Queens" selected="selected">Queens</option>
                                          <option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</option>

                                          <option value="Bronx">Bronx</option>
                                          <option value="Manhattan">Manhattan</option>
                                    </select>               
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

So it looks like it thinks borough is always emply?

Comment: Where is that `borough` come from? Are you sure that's not emptied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "commandName" attribute in your `<form:form>`? You will need to reference borough as a property of your command object. For example:

```
<c:when test="${empty command.borough}">
```